# rails order array by value when not in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I created an array in a rails runner(this is not a model and has no attributes) like:

```
name_1 = 5
name_2 = 14
name_3 = 26
name_4 = 3
...

 @names = [name_1, name_2, name_3, name_4, name_5]
```

Each "name_x" has an integer stored as its value.

How can I order the array so that it orders the output [highest  => lowest] by the current values, and also shows the "name" [key, value] ?.

Currently,

```
puts @names
```

shows only the values with no order.  Tks for pointing me in the right direction, theres many posts relating arrays but most asume its a model with attributes where you can say to order by the attribute. how do you order when you have no specific attributes like in this scenario?

Comment: Can you explain *also shows the "name" [key, value]*? What do you mean by that?

Comment: Sorry if my explanation not correct... I want to see the value and the name of the reference to that value, it is stored like "name _1 = 5" and it is a long list with lots of names, I need to know what is equal to "5", or ..where is the value coming from...  and what is equal to 14, 26 and so on... its a very long list.

Comment: Maybe im storing the values incorrectly, maybe theres a better way?

Comment: There is no ordinary way to do that. The moment your `name_1` is interpreted, it becomes `5`, nothing other than `5`. There is no way to retrieve how it was called. `5` is just `5`.

Comment: but, an array is not storing your "name" at all, just the values `[3, 5, 14, 26]`. You can order it, but it still wont have your variable names. Why not use a hash?

Comment: It could work. If you show me as an answer Ill mark as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want names (keys) and values, use a [`Hash`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/Hash.html).

```
@names = {name_1: 5, name_2: 14, name_3: 26, name_4: 3}
```

A `Hash` is [`Enumerable`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/Enumerable.html), so you can sort it. However sorting results in an array, but its easy to make that a `Hash` again, and hashes in Ruby maintain the order of insertion.

```
@names.sort_by{|k,v| v}
[[:name_4, 3], [:name_1, 5], [:name_2, 14], [:name_3, 26]]

@names.sort_by{|k,v| v}.to_h
{:name_4=>3, :name_1=>5, :name_2=>14, :name_3=>26}
```

The natural sort order is ascending (smallest to largest), but you can just negate the `sort_by` value, or reverse the resulting array.

```
@names.sort_by{|k,v| -v}.to_h
{:name_3=>26, :name_2=>14, :name_1=>5, :name_4=>3}

@names.sort_by{|k,v| v}.reverse.to_h
{:name_3=>26, :name_2=>14, :name_1=>5, :name_4=>3}
```